# Euclidean Algorithm in Polynomials $\Bbb Z_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Express the greatest common divisor of the following pair of polynomials as a combination of polynomials:
$f(x) = x^3 + x^2 +x +1$ and $g(x) = x^4 + x^2 + 1$.

I've been trying to understand this, but still can't get how I should do it in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Comment: When dividing should I care about the coefficients or the exponents?

Comment: The division algorithm is the same as always, except you perform coefficient arithmetic modulo $2$. For a convenient way to perform the extended Euclidean algorithm [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Comment: So I used the Eucl. Algorithm with  f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1 and g(x)=x^4+x^2+1 as normally, and kept dividing until I got 3 in the remainder. So since 3 = 2 in Z2, I don't know what to do next. Stop dividing?

Comment: $3=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: See the link I gave. You need to do the euclidean algorithm while simultaneously  keeping track of each remainder as a linear combination of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s really nothing different from solving such problems in $\Bbb Z$.

Using the Euclidean algorithm in its most straightforward form, not trying to be mechanically efficient:

$$\begin{align*}
x^4+x^2+1&=(x+1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)+x^2\\
x^3+x^2+x+1&=(x+1)x^2+(x+1)\\
x^2&=x(x+1)+x\\
x+1&=1\cdot x+\color{red}{1}
\end{align*}$$

The gcd is in red. Working upwards, and taking advantage of the fact that subtraction in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ is addition, we have

$$\begin{align*}
1&=1\cdot(x+1)+1\cdot x\\
&=1\cdot(x+1)+1\cdot\left(x^2+x(x+1)\right)\\
&=(x+1)(x+1)+1\cdot x^2\\
&=(x+1)\left(f(x)+(x+1)x^2\right)+1\cdot x^2\\
&=(x+1)f(x)+\left((x+1)^2+1\right)x^2\\
&=(x+1)f(x)+x^2\cdot x^2\\
&=(x+1)f(x)+x^2\Big(g(x)+(x+1)f(x)\Big)\\
&=\left(x+1+x^2(x+1)\right)f(x)+x^2 g(x)\\
&=(x+1)\left(x^2+1\right)f(x)+x^2 g(x)\\
&=(x+1)^3 f(x)+x^2 g(x)\;.
\end{align*}$$

As Bill Dubuque points out, and as is illustrated for numerical problems in the Wikipedia article on the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), there are more efficient ways to carry out the computations, but this is perhaps the easiest way to see clearly exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code
package polynomial;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class PolyFunction {
    private int degree;
    private int coeff[];

```
PolyFunction(int deg, int coef) {
    this.coeff = new int [deg+1];
    this.coeff[deg] = coef;
    this.degree  = deg;
}
int getDegree() {
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coeff.length; i++)
        if (coeff[i] != 0) d = i;
    return d;
}
void checkMode(int primeNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= getDegree(); i++) {
        coeff[i] %= primeNumber;
        if (coeff[i] < 0) 
            coeff[i] += primeNumber;
    }

}

PolyFunction addition(PolyFunction gx,int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;     
    PolyFunction fPlusG = new PolyFunction(Math.max(fx.degree, gx.degree),0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= fx.degree; i++) {
        fPlusG.coeff[i] += fx.coeff[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= gx.degree; i++) {
        fPlusG.coeff[i] += gx.coeff[i];
    }
    fPlusG.checkMode(primeNumber);
    return fPlusG;
}

PolyFunction minus(PolyFunction gx, int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;
    PolyFunction fMinusg = new PolyFunction(Math.max(fx.degree, gx.degree), 0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= fx.degree; i++) {
        fMinusg.coeff[i] += fx.coeff[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= gx.degree; i++) {
        fMinusg.coeff[i] -= gx.coeff[i];
    }
    fMinusg.checkMode(primeNumber);
    //fMinusg.degree = fMinusg.getDegree();
    return fMinusg;
}

PolyFunction multiple(PolyFunction gx) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;
    PolyFunction fMulg = new PolyFunction(fx.degree + gx.degree, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= fx.degree; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= gx.degree; j++)
            fMulg.coeff[i+j] += (fx.coeff[i] * gx.coeff[j]);

    return fMulg;
}

PolyFunction[] PLDA(PolyFunction gx, int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx  = this;

    fx.checkMode(primeNumber);
    gx.checkMode(primeNumber);

    PolyFunction []qr = new PolyFunction[2]; 
    qr[1] = fx;
    qr[0] = new PolyFunction(0,0);

    int degofQ = fx.getDegree() - gx.getDegree() ;

    if (degofQ == 0 && gx.getDegree() == 0) {
        //System.out.println("deg is zero");
        int temp [] = EEA(primeNumber, gx.coeff[0]);
        int divResult = (qr[1].coeff[qr[1].getDegree()] * temp[1]);

        divResult %= primeNumber;
        if ( divResult < 0) 
            divResult += primeNumber;
        qr[0] = new PolyFunction((qr[1].getDegree()-gx.getDegree()), divResult);
        qr[1] = new PolyFunction(0, 0);
        return qr;
    }

    if (degofQ < 0) {

        qr[1] = gx;
        qr[0] = fx;
        return qr;
    }

    while((qr[1].getDegree() >= gx.getDegree()) && (qr[1].getDegree()!=0 && qr[1].coeff[0]!=0)) {

        int [] temp = EEA(primeNumber,gx.coeff[gx.getDegree()]);

        int divResult = (qr[1].coeff[qr[1].getDegree()] * temp[1]);

        divResult %= primeNumber;
        if ( divResult < 0) 
            divResult += primeNumber;
        PolyFunction tx = new PolyFunction((qr[1].getDegree()-gx.getDegree()), divResult);

        qr[0] = qr[0].addition(tx,primeNumber);

        PolyFunction txgx = tx.multiple(gx);

        qr[1] = qr[1].minus(txgx,primeNumber);

        qr[0].checkMode(primeNumber);
        qr[1].checkMode(primeNumber);

    }
    return qr;
}

PolyFunction[] EEAP(PolyFunction gx,int primeNumber) {
    PolyFunction fx = this;
    PolyFunction []qr = new PolyFunction[2];

    if ((gx.getDegree() == 0) && gx.coeff[0] == 0) {            
        int [] temp = EEA(primeNumber,fx.coeff[fx.getDegree()]);

        int divResult = (1 * temp[1]);
        divResult %= primeNumber;
        if ( divResult < 0) 
            divResult += primeNumber;

        qr[0] = new PolyFunction(0, divResult);
        qr[1] = new PolyFunction(0, 0);
        return qr;
    }
    else {
            PolyFunction []R = new PolyFunction[2];
            qr = fx.PLDA(gx,primeNumber);
            PolyFunction q = qr[0];
            PolyFunction r = qr[1];
            R = gx.EEAP(r,primeNumber);

            PolyFunction ux = R[1];
            ux.checkMode(primeNumber);

            PolyFunction vx = R[0].minus(q.multiple(R[1]), primeNumber);
            vx.checkMode(primeNumber);
            return new PolyFunction[]{ux,vx};
    }
}

public int[] EEA(int a, int b){        
    if(b == 0){             
        return new int[]{1,0};                        
    } else {
        int q = a/b; 
        int r = a%b;
        int[] R = EEA(b,r);   
        return new int[]{R[1], R[0]-q*R[1]};
    }
}
public String toString() {
    if (degree ==  0) return "" + coeff[0];
    if (degree ==  1) return coeff[1] + "x + " + coeff[0];

    String ret = coeff[getDegree()] + "x^" + getDegree();

    for (int i = getDegree()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if      (coeff[i] == 0) continue;
        else if (coeff[i]  > 0) ret = ret + " + " + ( coeff[i]);
        else if (coeff[i]  < 0) ret = ret + " - " + (-coeff[i]);
        if      (i == 1) ret = ret + "x";
        else if (i >  1) ret = ret + "x^" + i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

public class GF2 {
    private PolyFunction fx;
    private PolyFunction gx;
    private PolyFunction mx;
    private int primeNumber;

```
GF2(String file) {
    fx = gx = mx = null;
    if (readInput(file) == -1) 
        return;
    System.out.println("PrimeNumber is " + primeNumber);
    System.out.println("mx is " + mx);
    System.out.println("fx is " + fx);
    System.out.println("gx is " + gx);
}
private int readInput(String file) {
    int mxDeg = 0, fxDeg = 0, gxDeg = 0;
    try {
        int counter = 1;
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String data = null;

        while(( data= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            switch(counter) {
            case 1:
                primeNumber = Integer.parseInt(data);
                break;
            case 2:
                mxDeg = Integer.parseInt(data);
                break;
            case 3:
                String [] mxToken = data.split("\\s+");
                PolyFunction []p = new PolyFunction[mxToken.length+1];
                for(int i=0; i < mxToken.length; i++) {
                     p[i] = new PolyFunction(mxDeg-i, Integer.parseInt(mxToken[i]));
                }
                mx = p[0];
                for(int i=1; i < mxToken.length; i++)
                    mx = mx.addition(p[i],primeNumber);
                break;
            case 4:
                fxDeg = Integer.parseInt(data);;
                break;
            case 5:
                String [] fxToken = data.split("\\s+");
                PolyFunction []pf = new PolyFunction[fxToken.length+1];
                for(int i=0; i < fxToken.length; i++) {
                     pf[i] = new PolyFunction(fxDeg-i, Integer.parseInt(fxToken[i]));
                }
                fx = pf[0];
                for(int i=1; i < fxToken.length; i++) 
                    fx = fx.addition(pf[i], primeNumber);
                break;
            case 6:
                gxDeg = Integer.parseInt(data);
            case 7:
                String [] gxToken = data.split("\\s+");
                PolyFunction []pg = new PolyFunction[gxToken.length+1];
                for(int i=0; i < gxToken.length; i++) {
                     pg[i] = new PolyFunction(gxDeg-i, Integer.parseInt(gxToken[i]));
                }
                gx = pg[0];
                for(int i=1; i < gxToken.length; i++) 
                    gx = gx.addition(pg[i],primeNumber);
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }   
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Input file is not able to open");
        return -1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
void dmas() {
    System.out.println("Addition is : " + fx.addition(gx, primeNumber));
    System.out.println("Subtraction is : " + fx.minus(gx, primeNumber));
    PolyFunction fMulg = fx.multiple(gx);
    if (fMulg.getDegree() >= mx.getDegree()) {
        fMulg = fMulg.PLDA(mx,primeNumber)[1];
        fMulg.checkMode(primeNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("Multiplication is : " + fMulg.toString());

    PolyFunction fDivg = mx.EEAP(gx,primeNumber)[1];
    fDivg = fx.multiple(fDivg);
    if (fDivg.getDegree() >= mx.getDegree()) {
        fDivg = fDivg.PLDA(mx,primeNumber)[1];
        fDivg.checkMode(primeNumber);
    }

    System.out.println("Division is : " + fDivg);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = "src\\polynomial\\myinput.txt";
    GF2 obj = new GF2(file);
    obj.dmas();
}
```

}